# Fastest way to spread 4 bytes into 8 bytes (32bit -> 64bit)

Tags: c++, c, performance, low-level-code

Assume you have a 32-bit unsigned integer, where the bytes are organized like this: `a b c d`.
What is the fastest way to spread these bytes into a 64-bit unsigned integer in this fashion:
`0 a 0 b 0 c 0 d`? It is for the `x86-64` architecture. I would like to know the fastest approach without using special intrinsics, although that would also be interesting.
(I say 'fastest', but compact solutions with reasonable performance is also nice).

Edit for people who want context. This seems like a really easy work, just shifting some bytes around, yet it requires more instructions than you'd think ([check this godbolt with optimizations](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:36,endLineNumber:7,positionColumn:36,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:36,selectionStartLineNumber:7,startColumn:36,startLineNumber:7),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Auint64_t+spread64(uint64_t+x)%0A%7B%0A++++return+((x+%3C%3C+24)+%26+0xFF000000000000)+%7C%0A++++++++((x+%3C%3C+16)++++%26+0xFF00000000)+%7C%0A++++++++((x+%3C%3C+8)+++++%26+0xFF0000)+%7C%0A++++++++(x+%26+0xFF)%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g102,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),fontScale:14,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:12,positionLineNumber:16,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:12,startLineNumber:16),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+10.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)). Therefore I just wonder if anyone knows of a way that would solve the problem with fewer instructions.

Comment: Probably just bit shifting then XOR-ing them together

Comment: What have you tried - please edit your best code into your question and eplain why you think it isn’t what you need

Comment: from the `performance` tag: "For questions pertaining to the measurement or improvement of code and application efficiency." You have nothing to measure or improve yet. Unless you have something, anything **is** the fastest. Smells like premature optimization. Please show your code

Comment: This works for 16-bit to 32-bit spreading: `((x * 0x0101010101010101L & 0x8040201008040201L) * 0x0102040810204081L >> 49) & 0x5555`. Taken from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36369006/how-to-spread-bits-in-a-byte).

Comment: The updated function is fine. The alternative is a loop which would add a handful of additional instructions.

Comment: Pick whatever you like the most https://godbolt.org/z/3E7Gsa but take into consideration that on x86_64, less instructions doesn't necessarily mean faster execution time.

Comment: Fastest would be a very large lookup table.

Comment: @AlexLop. I like the additional solution of using a union. I know less instructions does not mean faster execution time, but judging based on execution time is too machine dependant. Generated instructions is easier to compare.

Comment: @stark Maybe so, but I would not consider a naive 32 GB lookup table a reasonable or practical way of solving this problem. Maybe a nice mixed implementation, with a small lookup table and few instructions is possible though.

Comment: *I like the additional solution of using a union.*  The downside of using a union for type punning is **undefined behavior** in C++.

Comment: Are you only going to do this once? Or on a stream  of `int`s? Sounds like a job for SIMD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
uint64_t x = ...;
// 0 0 0 0 a b c d
x |= x << 16;
// 0 0 a b ? ? c d
x = x << 8 & 0x00ff000000ff0000 | x & 0x000000ff000000ff;
// 0 a 0 b 0 c 0 d
```

And for completeness, modern x86 processors can do this with one quick instruction:

```
x = _pdep_u64(x, 0xff00ff00ff00ff)
```

Comment: I like it! Shorter and saves 3 operations when compared to the godbolt I provided in the question.

Comment: wouldn't _pdep_u64(x, 0xff00ff00ff00ff) simply pass on the bits at the indicated locations? It has a 32 bit input and 32 bit output. The only instruction(s) I've found that can do the requested byte-to-word transformation are the various forms of punpack. And on x64 the only one I've found takes either the high or low __m128i of an __m256i and spreads it over the whole __m256i. 32-bit code may have a 32 to 64 bit version but I've found no way to make that work in x64 code.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, the task is to pass bits to indicated locations. It is equivalent to other solutions https://godbolt.org/z/7vq49n

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

_mm256_cvtepu8_epi16(eight_bit_numbers): takes a 128-bit vector of sixteen 8-bit numbers, and converts it to a 256-bit vector of sixteen 16-bit signed integers. For example:

```
 __m128i value1 = _mm_setr_epi8(0x11, 0x22, 0x33, 0x44, 
    0x55, 0x66, 0x77, 0x88, 0x99, 0xaa, 0xbb, 0xcc, 0xdd, 0xee, 0xff, 0x00);
 __m256i value2 = _mm256_cvtepu8_epi16(value1);
```

Or for 32-bit -> 64-bit:

https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#text=_mm256_cvtepu32_epi64